Proving a corollary about normal operators
I am trying to prove the following corollary:
Let $H$ be a Hilbert space, $B(H)$ denote the linear and bounded operators on $H$ and consider $H$ to be over $\mathbb{C}$.
Part a)
Let $T \in B(H)$. The following are equivalent:

$T$ is normal
there exists self adjoint operators $T_1,T_2 \in B(H) $ that commute (i.e. $T_1T_2=T_2T_1$) such that $T=T_1+iT_2$ (where $T_1$ and $T_2$ are unique).

Part b)
An operator $T \in B(H)$ is called positive, if $\langle Tx,x\rangle \geq 0$ for every $x \in H$. Let $T \in B(H)$ be normal, then $T$ can be written as a linear combination of four positive operators that commute with each other.
What I did:
($1 \Rightarrow 2$):
Suppose T is normal, i.e. $T^*T=TT^*$.
Define
$(1)$ $T_1=\frac{1}{2}(T+T^*)$ and $T_2=\frac{1}{2i}(T-T^*)$.
Then $T_1+iT_2=T$.
$T_1$ is self adjoint since $(T+T^*)=T^*+T^**=T*+T$
Analoguos $T_2$ is (skew) self adjoint. And
$T_1T_2=\frac{1}{4i}(T+T^*)(T-T^*)=\frac{1}{4i} T^2-TT^*+T^*T-(T^*)^2=\frac{1}{4i} T^2-T^*T+TT^*-(T^*)^2=T_2T_1$
$(2 \Rightarrow 1)$:
Suppose 2. holds:
Then because $T_1T_2=T_2T_1$ and $T_1,T_2$ are self adjoint we get that $T^*T=TT^*$.
That's how far I came. But at the moment I am struggling with Part b). I assume there is a similar way to $(1)$ to write $T$, but I couldn't think of how to.
Edit:
For context, I recently started learning about functional calculus. Although I did get the Statement of the Theorem, I had the feeling that I did not really "connect the dots" on that topic. That's why I tried to do some examples, but did not know how to approach them using functional calculus. So what I now want, is a detailed example of how one approaches problems using functional calculus. I found the above stated corollary, but was not able to prove Part b).
If someone know (and would be kind enough) to explain this, I would be very grateful.
(By the way, if someone knows some literature where there are detailed examples of functional calculus, let me know.)

For (b), this depends on what you know. If you’ve already seen functional calculus, use that. Otherwise, note that for a self-adjoint $T$, we have $T = \frac{1}{2}[(|T| I + T) - (|T| I - T)]$. Then prove that $|T| I + T$ and $|T| I - T$ are both positive operators.

@DavidGao This should be done using functional calculus. But I am fairly new to this topic and do not really know how to do that.

@Peter How much do you know about functional calculus?

I am at just the beginning. Started learning it today. I have seen a Theorem called "Continuous functional calculus" and I wanted to try and do some exercises. But it seems that I do not really get the idea behind it. Thus, I wanted to (if possible) see a more detailed example of how one uses functional calculus to solve problems. Thats why I posted the question here.

@Peter Maybe you should edit the Question then to state it more clearly.

@Philip I did edit the question to include more context.

@Peter If you want to prove this using continuous functional calculus, simply note that the following four functions (of a complex variable $z$) are continuous: $f_1(z) = \max{\text{Re}(z), 0}$, $f_2(z) = \max{-\text{Re}(z), 0}$, $f_3(z) = \max{\text{Im}(z), 0}$, $f_4(z) = \max{-\text{Im}(z), 0}$. Observe that $z = f_1(z) - f_2(z) + if_3(z) - if_4(z)$. Also observe that all four functions are positive. Hence, $T = f_1(T) - f_2(T) + if_3(T) - if_4(T)$ and $f_i(T)$ are positive operators that commute with each other.

@DavidGao Thank you very much!

There is an advantage of functional calculus. Namely $f_1f_2=f_3f_4=0,$ hence the decomposition is optimal.

@RyszardSzwarc Indeed. Though the approach using $|T|I + T$ and $|T|I - T$ has a different advantage, namely, it shows you don't actually need a $C^\ast$ algebra in order to have this decomposition (which would be necessary if you're using continuous functional calculus). Instead, just an operator system (a $\ast$-closed subspace containing the identity) is enough.

@DavidGao I prefer an elementary decomposition where only definitions and Cauchy-Schwarz is used. That's why I wanted to point out the advantage of a non elementary method, as otherwise there is no justification for applying it.

@DavidGao How did you come up with $f_1,...,f_4$? I.e. why is $f_1(z)=max{Re(z),0},f_2(z)$.... and so on.

@Peter It’s just taking positive part and negative part. The function $x \mapsto \max{x, 0}$ is just the positive part of $x$, i.e., $x$ when $x \geq 0$ and $0$ otherwise. So $f_1(z)$ is the positive part of $\text{Re}(z)$. Similarly, $f_2$ is the negative part of $\text{Re}(z)$ and so on.

@DavidGao Thank you!
